# with extern C but "has not had a body defined" error

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, googletest, extern

I have a C library `A` with no test and I am trying to add tests for one of its functions `funC`:

in `funC` is not declared in `A/lib.h` and only declared in `A/lib.c`:

```
static int funC();

static int funC(){
    // do something
}
```

and I created a test file in `test/A.t.cpp` and want to access funC to test it. funC is only declared in .c file so i decide to use `extern C`. in `test/A.t.cpp` I have:

```
extern "C"{
    static int funC();
}

TEST(A,test){
    funC();
    .....
}
```

I thought with the declaration in the .t.cpp file, it would be able to link against the actual implementation in the .c file so I should be able to call the function and test it, but I got:

`Error: The function funC() has not had a body defined`

how should I fix it?  Then I also tried to add the implementation within the test file and it worked but that's not what I want. I want the .t.cpp file to link against the actual implementation in .c file. Thanks!

Comment: `static` functions are not _visible_ outside of their compilation unit... That's what **static** means...

Comment: @dbush has provided one possibility.... Or, you could 'temporarily' comment out the 'static' keyword so the function is visible to other code modules.... Or, you could use `#ifdef` to hide the uninteresting functions and write the C test code inside the same source file. Or you could call the function(s) in that module that rely on that static (helper) function... Many ways to test...

Comment: A _subtle_ consideration when thinking of testing a static function in isolation is that you will be bypassing any _protection_ offered by the functions that use the static function. The coder may not have bothered to defend against null pointers, division by zero or seeking the square root of a negative number because other functions already preclude that sort of bad data being passed to the static function... It's not simply a matter of pushing it until it breaks... It may be static for a reason...

Comment: Along the lines of what dbush suggested, you could create a file `wrapper.c` that includes `A/lib.c` and then provides a function that calls `funcC`, e.g. `int funcC_wrapper() { return funcC(); }`. Then the test code calls `funcC_wrapper()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `funC()` has internal linkage (this is the meaning of `static` for functions and file-scope variables in C).  It cannot be called by name from other translation units than the one it is defined in, whether C or C++.

In your test source, the same name refers to a different function, for which you have not provided a definition.

If you want `funC()` to be callable from your separate test file then you should change it to have external linkage by removing its `static` qualifier or changing it to `extern`.  You will need to make the same change to the declaration in the test file.

Comment: @CPP, If the function is not public then you cannot call it (by name) from a different file, including the one where your test is defined.  Your options are (i) don't test it (directly); (ii) make it public by giving it external linkage; or (iii) do something *really* hacky, such as sneaking out a pointer to it, or `#include`ing its source file into your test source.  As far as I am concerned, providing for testability is a valid reason to give functions external linkage, but YMMV.

Comment: thanks. I don't know if testing purpose is a valid reason to make a private function public ... that is debatable

Answer (score 0):

To unit test static functions, this is one of the rare cases where you would need to include a .c file:

```cpp
extern "C"{

#include "A/lib.c"

}

TEST(A,test){
    funC();
    .....
}
```

Then the `static` functions and variables will be visible in the test code.

Comment: @CPP Then you did something else wrong.  The module that tests the code in A/lib.c should test *only* that code.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a bad idea.  C and C++ are different languages, as you well know.  It is by no means safe to assume that C code can be compiled successfully as C++, or that if it *is* compiled successfully that it will mean the same thing as when it is compiled as C.  I wouldn't really recommend this for tests written in C, but it fundamentally flawed for tests written in C++.

Comment: @CPP No, you would keep A/lib.c as is, and test/A.t.cpp would *only* contain code necessary to test those function.  And actually a good point was brought up.  You should be testing C code in a C module, not a C++ module as it could behave differently.

Comment: @CPP That depends entirely on what test code you have and what errors you're getting.  And if it's possible to write the test code in C instead of C++ you should do so.